# how can i get debug map api key?

Tags: android, google-maps

```
C:\Users\Bladeszasza>keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey \ -keystore <C:\Users\
Bladeszasza\.android>.keystore \ -storepass android -keypass android
Access is denied.
```

I get that error it is the first time i want to use the keystore.I need to get the map api key but i m unable to generate the md5 fingerprint.Cna you help me.An i alredy have read this [site](http://code.google.com/intl/sk-SK/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html#getdebugfingerprint)

thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick provided the location is correct.

```
C:\Users\Bladeszasza>keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\Bladeszasza\.android\keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In command line  you need to open Java-> jdk-> bin 
   as for me  it  is "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin"
2. There is "keytool" program which u need. In command line enter "cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin"
3. And enter "keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\John\.android\debug.keystore"
   So the final string in command line must look like:
   "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\John\.android\debug.keystore". Whare usually u need only to change the name "John"

There will be SHA-1, MD5, etc

Finally, go to Google Access API [google access api](https://code.google.com/apis/console/#project:32596228624%3aaccess)